# Why can't I specify the correct NumPy size?

Tags: python, neural-network, keras, numpy

In the network (model of Keras, Sequential), the input layer must have 4 neurons. The input must be 1 list, the length of which is 4, each element is a number.

```
print("SHAPE:", np.array([1, 1, 1, 1]).shape)

self.model.fit(np.array([1, 1, 1, 1]),
self.rightAnswer, 
epochs = 1,
batch_size = 1)
```

Here is the conclusion:

```
SHAPE: (4,)

ValueError: Error when checking input: expected dense_1_input to have shape (4,) but got array with shape (1,)
```

Why is this happening, and how can I fix it?

Comment: please post your `model.fit` function in order to understand what it requires

Comment: I have already: self.model.fit(np.array([1, 1, 1, 1]),
self.rightAnswer, 
epochs = 1,
batch_size = 1)

Comment: This is the **call** to the function, I meant the function itself, what does it do, how is it implemented

Comment: Ohh, I haven't write that I use Keras. It is the function of Keras Sequential model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keras needs you to pass one more dimension than it says in the error message: the **batch dimension**.

I.e.

If you have a model that requires each sample to have an input shape of `(4,)` and you have 1000 training samples you need to feed it with an array of `(1000, 4)`.

In your case since you want to feed it with just one sample you need to pass a shape of `(1, 4)`. Try `self.model.fit(np.array([[1, 1, 1, 1]]))` (notice the one extra bracket with makes the array's shape be `(1, 4)`) .